# What is the name of anime about warrior that has to collect crystal sword, ball, mirror?

Tags: master-of-mosquiton

I am completely sure that I watched this anime before 2006, and I'm quite sure that I watched it before 2003, probably around 2000. Those were strange days when the cable TV showed amines and movies that you can find now (almost).

I'm not sure which country the anime is from, but the warrior did look somewhat like a samurai.

I watched at least 3 episodes, and in each episode, the warrior found an object which gave him a new ability.

- In the first episode, he got a sword after defeating a boss (something that looked like Jabba the Hutt from Star Wars, but motorized like a rocker). He gained the ability to change his size and became big. He also found a girl in the first episode.
- In the second episode, I remember them walking in some woods and some people were tailing them. After that, they met the second boss and he defeated him. Both became big in size as they were fighting. The boss had a yellow armor and he had a spear (?). The warrior received a mirror after defeating the 2nd boss.
- In the third episode, I vividly remember some of his friends escaping around the end of the episode. The guy was in Egypt and 2 sphinxes started to move and fight him, but he and the girl started to sink in quicksand, and that's the end of the episode. In this episode, they were supposed to acquire the crystal sphere.

It would be great if someone can help with name, year, country or anything.

Comment: Can you tell us When you watched this? This could help narrow down the time period.

Comment: The style looked very old it looked before 2000, probably something like 1995-1998. But not 70s or even early 80 although I wouldn't know for sure.

Comment: No, what I'm asking is when *you* watched it. What was the year (approximately) when you saw this on TV. If for instance you saw it in 2000, we'll know that it can't be a 2001 anime ... etc.

Comment: 100% before 2006, quite quite(97%) sure before 2003, probably around 2000

Comment: FYI, the sword / jewel / mirror are the three [Imperial Regalia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperial_Regalia_of_Japan) of Japan, so they are a recurring thematic element across multiple anime. You might like to consult [this revision](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Imperial_Regalia_of_Japan&diff=prev&oldid=292674639) of the Wikipedia article, which contains a list of pop culture references to the Regalia. See also [this TVTropes page](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Imperial_Regalia_of_Japan&diff=prev&oldid=292674639), section "Imperial Regalia".

Comment: @senshin I assume you meant to link to [Requisite Royal Regalia](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/RequisiteRoyalRegalia) for the TV Tropes link.

Comment: @Krazer Whoops. I actually meant to link to [Public Domain Artifact](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/PublicDomainArtifact).

Comment: In that case, it sounds like [Yu-Yu-Hakusho](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YuYu_Hakusho).

Comment: It is not Yu-Yu-Hakusho, also I remembered that the theme seemed a little post-apocalyptic, that is why the warrior was defeating these bosses I think.

Comment: I think the anime might be as obscure as Lazenca although I managed to find this one recently.

Comment: Also I remembered that the clothing of the main characher(the warrior) was mostly gray. And it looked traditionally eastern. I can't tell if it was Korean, Japanese or Chinese, or ant other.

Answer (score 3):

There is an anime that fits your description. It's called Master Mosquiton 99. The third episode takes place in egypt. In this episode at least one sphinx comes to life. It's also about defeating a boss in every episode and collecting treasure that has magic powers. 
It originally aired from 1997 to 1998.

http://en.anisearch.com/anime/2030,master-mosquiton-99